# Jquery DateTime now showing ValidationMessageFor for a field with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have the Model with the following declaration

```
    [Display(Name = "lblFechaInicio", ResourceType = typeof(RecursosAdministracion))]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime? fechaInicio { get; set; }
```

In the View I have this:

```
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.fechaInicio, new { @class = "control-label" })
<div class="controls">
    <div class="input-prepend">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.fechaInicio, new { @class = "input-small hasDatepicker" })
        <span class="add-on">
            <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <span class="help-inline">
        <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="@Model.fechaInicio" class="field-validation-error">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.fechaInicio)
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```

But when I type an invalid Date in `fechaInicio` and move to another field, the validation is not being fired and the validation message if not being shown

[image]
Below is the list of all the included scripts of the rendered page

```
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/DataTables-1.9.4/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/ScriptsArq/jquery.dataTables.custom.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/ScriptsArq/WrapperUI.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/ScriptsArq/ScriptUtilitarios.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/ScriptsArq/CustomDataTablesPlugin.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/ScriptsArq/utf8.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/ScriptsArq/jquery.fileDownload.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/ScriptsArq/metro-base.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/Vistas/Helpers.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/suppt-ui-utilitarios.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/select2.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/select2.culture-es.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/ReportViewer/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.culture-es.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/WebSite/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-custom-for-bootstrap.js"></script>
```

The file `jquery.ui.datepicker.culture-es.js` contains this
    $(document).ready(function() {

```
    $(function($) {
        $.datepicker.regional["es"] = {
            closeText: "Cerrar",
            prevText: "<Ant",
            nextText: "Sig>",
            currentText: "Hoy",
            monthNames: [
                "Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre",
                "Noviembre", "Diciembre"
            ],
            monthNamesShort: ["Ene", "Feb", "Mar", "Abr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dic"],
            dayNames: ["Domingo", "Lunes", "Martes", "Miércoles", "Jueves", "Viernes", "Sábado"],
            dayNamesShort: ["Dom", "Lun", "Mar", "Mié", "Juv", "Vie", "Sáb"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Do", "Lu", "Ma", "Mi", "Ju", "Vi", "Sá"],
            weekHeader: "Sm",
            dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
            firstDay: 1,
            isRTL: false,
            showMonthAfterYear: false,
            yearSuffix: ""
        };
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"]);
    });

});
```

What I am expecting is this behaviour

[image]

I have searched in here and other websites without any luck to find out what is missing/wrong

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was something very obvious.

You need to have a `@using Html.BeginForm` in your view that contains the inputs/fields that you are validating